# How to update Adobe Flash from command line?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line-interface, flash, update

Something I can stick in a shortcut or, **ideally, run silently and remotely** using [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) (from Sysinternals).

A WSUS server is out of the question. Machines needing the updates run Windows XP as kiosks.

I can't use the following call because this file no longer exists:

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Macromed\Flash\FlashUtil<version>_Plugin.exe -update plugin
```

Instead, I've can see the following files in `C:\WINDOWS\system32\Macromed\Flash`:

```
Flash10x.ocx
FlashInstall.log
FlashUtil10x_ActiveX.dll
FlashUtil10x_ActiveX.exe
```

I've tried `FlashUtil11c_ActiveX.exe /?`, but this doesn't give anything except an error.

Answer (score 6):

You can download MSI versions of Flash from adobe's [redistribution site](http://www.adobe.com/special/products/flashplayer/fp_distribution3.html). It's free to register for and you can deploy them via GPO or through a script with something like `Msiexec /I flash.msi /QB`

GPO is the most reliable way of the two, since psexec requires that the machine is on.

Comment: Technically, they both require the machine to be on ;-)

Comment: @BartSilverstrim Smartass. Psexec requires the machine to be on **when you run it**

Comment: Just out of curiosity, will this run the msi everytime the user boots up/logs in? I use SCE to push out flash and don't do it this way because I don't want to write some script that checks versions.  Will AD somehow just run it once? I suspect it runs everytime which might make things laggy if you have 5 MSIs in there.

Comment: If you deploy any software via GPO, it only installs each version a single time. I'm not sure about SCE, I don't use it.

Comment: Cheers for this. In my ignorance, what's GPO? Thanks.

Comment: @UmberFerrule Group Policy Objects.

Answer (score 4):

+1 for markMs answer and a little addition:

Also, the msi appears in your temp folder while the setup is running (just double-click the exe and check temp for new folders/files).

[AppDeploy](http://www.appdeploy.com/index.asp) has a list of command line switches for various applications, including [Flash](http://www.appdeploy.com/packages/detail.asp?id=798).

It should work with `psexec` once you've copied the setup onto the target computer.
If you don't have a software distribution system (like SCCM or netinstall) in your environment you could build a list of computers to run the `psexec` command on.

Comment: AppDeploy is very useful! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
FlashUtil10x_ActiveX.exe -update plugin
```

Then the update window will appear.  This will work for Flash for IE and other browsers like Opera; just make sure you find the right flash_xxxxxxxx.exe.